# Could not connect to the server Please verify the settings are correct

Tags: ftp

when i try to update wordpress then showing this message Error: Could not connect to the server. Please verify the settings are correct.
please tell me solution to fix issue
i am expected update wordpress without error
thanks

Comment: Can you connect to admin area? Have you added any new plugins lately? Tried disabling the plugins folder temporarily (rename it)? Used a 'twenty' theme?

Comment: This sounds like a hosting/wp-config file issue. I would check out the wp-config file and contact your hosting provider if they have any support.